# Javascript Loto Game

Tags: javascript

How can I check for matching numbers in this script, stuck here, I need to compare the array of user numbers with the array of lotto numbers and display how many numbers they got correct if any along with their prize value.

```
function numbers() {

    var numbercount = 6;
    var maxnumbers = 40;

    var ok = 1;
    r = new Array(numbercount);
    for (var i = 1; i <= numbercount; i++) {
        r[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * (maxnumbers - 1)) + 1;
    }
    for (var i = numbercount; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (var j = numbercount; j >= 1; j--) {
            if ((i != j) && (r[i] == r[j])) ok = 0;
        }
    }
    if (ok) {
        var output = "";
        for (var k = 1; k <= numbercount; k++) {
            output += r[k] + ", ";
        }
        document.lotto.results.value = output;
    } else numbers();

}

function userNumbers() {
    var usersNumbers = new Array(5);
    for (var count = 0; count <= 5; count++) {
        usersNumbers[count] = window.prompt("Enter your number " + (count + 1) + ": ");
    }
    document.lotto.usersNumbers.value = usersNumbers;
}
```

Comment: Could you detail the problem you're having some more?

Comment: Yep, this has to be improved. Right now, this Q falls under the following off-topic close reason: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate **a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. [See also: Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)*

Comment: I want to compare the elements of array userNumbers to the values of results to see if there are any matching numbers.

Comment: I'm working on an answer, but this question could use some help. I understand what's being asked for.

Comment: @Jessica You could edit your post to include the code you are trying to use to solve this problem. Don't mind if the code doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lotto numbers generator and a scoring system. I'm going to leave it to you to validate the user input.

```
function lottoGen(){
    var lottoNumbers = [];
    for(var k = 0; k<6; k++){
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
        if(lottoNumbers.indexOf(num) != -1){
            lottoNumbers.push(num);
        }
    }
        return lottoNumbers;
}

function scoreIt(){
    var usersNumbers = document.getElementsByName('usersNumbers').item(0);
    usersNumbers = String(usersNumbers)
    usersNumbers = usersNumbers.split(' ');
    var matches = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i<6; i++){
        if(lottoNumbers.indexOf(usersNumbers[i]) != -1){matches++;}
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Your lottoGen() function will not work as expected. I can see at least two issue there. Frist your random number can generate 0. Secound ... if number gets repeted you are shourt one or more numbers in your lottoNumbers array.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm new to this and trying to learn off my own back so obviously I'm no expert but the code above makes a lot of sense to me, apart from the fact I can't get it to work.. I tried to console.log where it says RETURN so I could see the numbers but it just shows an empty array still. I assumed this was to do with it being outside the loop..
I've tried various ways but the best I get is an array that loops the same number or an array with 6 numbers but some of which are repeated..

```
function lottoGen(){
    var lottoNumbers = [];
    for(var k = 0; k<6; k++){
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
        if(lottoNumbers.indexOf(num) != -1){
            lottoNumbers.push(num);
        }
    }
        return lottoNumbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lotto JS: [CODEPEN DEMO >> HERE <<](http://codepen.io/GlupiJas/pen/MyJyrj?editors=1111)

```
(function(){
  var btn = document.querySelector("button");
  var output = document.querySelector("#result");

  function getRandom(min, max){
      return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }

  function showRandomNUmbers(){
      var numbers = [], 
          random;

      for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){   

        random = getRandom(1, 49);
        while(numbers.indexOf(random) !== -1){
            console.log("upps (" + random + ") it is in already.");
            random = getRandom(1, 49);
            console.log("replaced with: (" + random + ").");
        }

        numbers.push(random);

      }

    output.value = numbers.join(", ");

  }
  btn.onclick = showRandomNUmbers;
})();
```